# DAC: What waveform should I expect when ramping up?

Tags: dac

I have a 14-bit DAC, [the AD9775BSV](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD9775.pdf). Ramping the data pins linearly from the minimum of `0x0` to the maximum of `0x3FFF` I see (using a scope) the analogue output voltage behaving as follows:

1. In the first half (from `0x0` to `0x2000`), the voltage ramps from `1V` to `1.8V`.
2. In the second half (from `0x2000` to `0x3FFF`), the voltage ramps from `0V` to `1V`.

Is this the expected behaviour? What output voltage range should I be expecting for the analogue output? Why is there a "break" at `0x2000`?

Comment: Can you tell us what DAC are you using?

Comment: I am using the `AD9775BSV`. The datasheet is linked in the question.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out part of the answer. The break is due to the two's complement option being turned on (see page 14):

> Logic “0” (default) causes data to be accepted on the inputs as two’s complement binary. Logic “1” causes data to be accepted as straight binary.

Comment: That makes sense, in that case the voltage output is not linear.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to figure out. I'm possibly a little off in my measurements.